# errors are not showing while php.ini file is set to do so

Tags: php

I have spend quite some time on google, but I cant get the showing of errors to the ui to work.

In the php.ini file I set the following :

```
error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
display_errors = On
```

with phpinfo() I see the following

```
Server API                  CGI/FastCGI
Loaded Configuration File   /home/totalteach/etc/php5/php.ini
```

So I know I have the correct php.ini file.
I understand that with FastCGI the apacheserver does not need to be restarted after a change in the php.ini, so I didnt.

My index.php looks like this :

```
<?php
print("The line below should generate an error.<br>"); 
printaline("This is the line that will generate an error."); 
print("This line will not be displayed due to the error caused by the above line."); 
?>
```

When I go to the site I only see "The line below should generate an error.", nothing else.
I would expect to see an error after it though.
What am I missing here..

Comment: put `phpinfo()` RIGHT before your printaline function, and see what the "local" settings for error_reporting/display_errors are. something else could be overriding them elsewhere. e.g. a .htaccess `php_value`.

Comment: are you a running your own server or a shared host?

Comment: under "Directive" I see:
`display_errors Off Off
display_startup_errors Off`

I have to look into this

Comment: Just got of the phone with a guy from the server hosting company. After messing around a bit, he did restart the server and then we saw the changes in the phpinfo() output. And at the bottom of the page :
`Fatal error: Call to undefined function printaline() in /home/totalteach/public_html/index.php on line 4`
So it seems a change in fastCGI does require a restart after all.